# How do you send a http request to a raspberry pi node server api

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi running a Node server using Express to set up different endpoints for an API. The server's IP Address is 192.168.x.y with some port..

I'm trying to send a request from my computer to the Raspberry Pi using the request npm package, and I keep getting Invalid protocol error.

Is it possible to use an actual IP Address to send a request to in my code? I also tried using axios but I was getting errors with that too.

My Raspberry Pi Server:

```
var express = require('express');        
var app = express();                 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require("fs");
const axios = require('axios');
const request = require('request');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'API is Online!' });   
});

app.listen(process.env.IP || 3000, process.env.IP, function () {
    console.log("server started");
});
```

My Client:

```
var express = require('express');        
var app = express();                 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 
        //my raspberry pi IP address and port
request('192.168.x.y:3000', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: You're missing the [_scheme_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax)... `request("http://192.168.x.y:3000/", ...)`. Personally, I'd just use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)

Comment: Yes, that's what I did in the orginal code.. but I get that Invalid Protocol error. But when I use Postman or Chrome to hit this endpoint, I do get some JSON back.

Comment: That's not what you've got in your question. Note the difference between `'192.168.x.y:3000'` and `'http://192.168.x.y:3000/'`

Comment: FYI `request` is deprecated. I highly recommend `axios` or `node-fetch`

Comment: Oh I see, it works now, thank you. I was using Chrome at first so it hided the scheme, didn't realize that.